# make an ajax call in the very first page in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show a popup in my first page if a php post returns a json file with data.

I tried with:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#home', function() {
    ajax call even with async:false,...
```

And after that, I fill up the

element with some list elements if json has data:

```
if(userLastPush == 1){
var getPushXdays = '{"day":"4"}';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlServer+"getPushXDays.php",
        data: getPushXdays,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            //console.log(response);
            html = '';

            if(response.message != "empty"){
            jQuery.each(response, function(category, val) {
                if(val.id_Event == 0){
                            html +='<li><a href="#myMessagesAll" data-transition="slide">' + val.message + '</a></li>';
                }else{
                            html +='<li><a href="#myMessagesEvent" data-transition="slide">' + val.message + '</a></li>';
                }


                         });
        }
            $(".popupPush").append(html).listview('refresh');
            if(checkPushing == 0){
                $("#checkpush").trigger("click");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, message) {}
        });
}
```

But it just works sometimes. Others, ajax never ends or never shows data. I tried by using a function instead and function is called but no return from ajax. Is there a way to make this getting all data before page is load?

Comment: you want to feed popup with ajax result and then open it?

Comment: yes, in the first page

Comment: You cant open a popup unless the page is fully shown. use `pageshow` (jQM <=1.3) `pagecontainershow` (jQM >= 1.4). Sometimes a _delay_ is required depending on devices's speed.

Comment: I am using pageshow now with jqm 1.3.1 and few times it works but most of them, pop up is never load. Even, I have a console.log in response function and never gets called. Thats why this a weird issue for me.

Comment: `$("#checkpush").trigger("click");` you can use `$("#popupID").popup("open")` instead. I dont know if it has to do with `async: false`.

Comment: I have discovered it just fail in chrome and android. In ios, winpho and firefox it works like a charm. I don't know why chrome doesn't execute pageshow function in #home but it does in the others tabs, I'll check your solution right now